# React навигация с помощью клавиатуры ul и table как реализовать?

Tags: reactjs, ui

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли какой-нибудь стандартный способ указать возможность навигации с помощью клавиатуры внутри элементов ul и table ? Как это реализовать ?

Comment: суть понятна, но на самом деле ничего не понятно. опишите подробнее, будьте так добры

Comment: Есть стандартный ul у которого несколько li необходимо чтобы юзер на странице мог использовать клавиатуру (стрелки вверх/вниз) чтобы перемещать фокус по элементам li и с помощью enter выбирать (click) этот li

Answer (score 1):

это просто Вам как **пример, не больше**. этот код совсем не адаптивный.

```js
const myList = [...Array(9)];  // это типа пропса (массив для <li>)

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      activeId: null
    };
    this.checkKeys = this.checkKeys.bind(this);
  }
  
  static getDerivedStateFromProps({ items }, state) {
    const store = items.map((i, n) => ({ id: n, isActive: false }));
    
    return state.list.length ? null : { list: store };
  }
  
  checkKeys(e) {
    e.persist();    // это чтобы объект событий работал как надо (гугл поможет)
    const { list, activeId } = this.state;
    let nextActiveId = activeId;
    
    if (activeId === null) {       // проверяем если ли уже выбранные блоки клавиатурой
        const newList = list.map(i => i.id == 0 ? { ...i, isActive: true } : i);
        
        return this.setState({ list: newList, activeId: 0 });
    }
    
    switch (e.keyCode) {  // проверяем какую клавишу нажали
       case 40: {
          nextActiveId += 3;
          break;
       }
       
       case 38: {
          nextActiveId -= 3;
          break;
       }
       
       case 39: {
          nextActiveId += 1;
          break;
       }
       
       case 37: {
         nextActiveId -= 1;
         break;
       }
       
       case 13: {
          alert(`Вы выбрали lolipop номер ${activeId + 1}`);
          break;
       }
    }
    
    // проверяем не вышли ли мы за границы блоков
    if (nextActiveId < 0 || nextActiveId > list.length - 1) return;
    
    this.setState({
        list: list.map(i => ({ ...i, isActive: (i.id === nextActiveId) })),
        activeId: nextActiveId
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul onKeyDown={this.checkKeys} tabIndex="0">
        {
          this.state.list.map((i, n) =>
              <li className={ i.isActive ? 'active' : '' } key={n}>lolipop</li>
          )
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<App items={myList} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: transform .5s, border .5s;
  font-size: 12px;
}

li.active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

здесь главная мысль в том, что `state.list` - это модель приложения (хранит состояния всех блоков - кто из них выбран, а кто - нет)