# React. Как добавить состояние при клике, и сбросить у других элементов?

Tags: reactjs

Как сделать состояние false, если кликнули по другому элементу во враппере?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const ContextMenuOption = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const _handleClick = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
    <button
      onClick={_handleClick}
      className={
        isActive
          ? 'context-menu-option context-button active'
          : 'context-menu-option context-button'
      }
    />
  );
}
```

**Update:**

Решил проблему с помощью рефов.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export const ContextMenuOption = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const ref = useRef(null);

  const _handleClickAway = (event) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
      setIsActive(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', _handleClickAway);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', _handleClickAway);
    };
  });


  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}
      ref={ref}
      className={
        isActive
          ? 'context-menu-option context-button active'
          : 'context-menu-option context-button'
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: то есть, как `isActive` сделать `false`, если кликнули не по этому экземпляру компонента?

Comment: @Август да, верно

Comment: Вам придется создать общее состояние всех экземплятов в родительском компоненте. если никто другой не предложит лучший вариант, я Вам дам ответ

Comment: @Август, я пробовал общее состояние, но как проверить на какой именно элемент был клик? Кидать много рефов?

Comment: вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099215/react-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-ul-%d0%b8-table-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c#comment1893859_1099215) я прям похожее отвечал. если не поймете как оно реализовано и как реализовать для Вашего вопроса - я напишу заново для Вас

Comment: @Август, благодарю